# Логическое умножение в Java

Tags: java

Число 2 в двоичной системе в Java - это 010. Число 59 в двоичной системе Java - это 0111011. Так вот в чем вопрос, если я попытаюсь выполнить логическое умножение, то как будет компенсировано различие в числе разрядов?

Comment: Думаю, будет добито слева 0, т.е. не `010`, а `0000010`

Comment: если числа одинакового типа (int например), то количество разрядов у них одинаковое.